# How to reference a global value without getting "object variable or with block not set" error?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a variable `listvalues` that is set as an arraylist. This variable is being populated in `form1` with a list of file paths but can also be left blank. Then after clicking a button1, `form1` gets closed and `report1` opens. In this report i have `button2` which is basically being used to export the report but also clears the `listvalues` and uses the file paths to append pdfs to the end of the report. However, i cannot seem to get passed the above error. I tried creating another global variable as an object called `attachedfiles` and do `Set attachedfiles = listvalues` in `form1` so that i can instead refer to `attachedfiles` and clear it but it doesnt work. I currently have a module made called `module2` with the global variables declared inside it as

```
Option Compare Database
Global listvalues As ArrayList
Global attachedfiles As Object
```

Basically i just need a way to transfer and make usable the arraylist of files selected in form1 but in another form called form2, id appreciate some direction on this!

Edit: here is the code for button1

```
Private Sub filebutton_Click()
Dim fDialog As filedialog
Dim selectedfile As Variant
'array create list, !!!!!!need to turn on .net framework 3.5 in system features
Set listvalues = New ArrayList

Set fDialog = Application.filedialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With fDialog
    'Existing filters must be cleared before adding new:
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "PDFs", "*.pdf"

If fDialog.Show = -1 Then
    For Each selectedfile In .SelectedItems
        listvalues.Add selectedfile
    Next
End If
End With

filedialog.ColumnCount = 1

Me.filedialog.RowSource = ""
For Each i In listvalues
    Me.filedialog.AddItem (i)
Next

Set attachedfiles = listvalues
End Sub
```

And for button2 which generates the pdf appended with the attached file paths in `attachedfiles`

```
Private Sub pdfbutton_Click()
Dim oPDF As PdfCreatorObj
Set oPDF = New PdfCreatorObj
MsgBox (attachedfiles.Count)
If attachedfiles.Count > 0 Then
    MsgBox ("attachedfiles")
    Dim attacheditemcount As String
    attacheditemcount = listvalues.Count
```

Idk if I have to reference the global variables in somewhere else instead of just a random module that doesnt get referenced or if i have to initialize the global variables before using them?

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? Where is the rest of the code where they are used?

Comment: @braX there isnt much code so far, i need to get the referencing to work before i add more, in report1 basically i have attachedfiles.clear and a msgbox function that is in a for i in attached files loop. But both of them throw the object variable not set error in report1 on_load event

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I did not mean for you to describe your other code, I was suggesting that you include it in your question.

Comment: Have you added the .net framework library as arraylist is not part of VBA.

Comment: @KL-1 ive checked off .Net framework 3.5 in system features already yes, idk if theres a vba reference i need to turn on?

Comment: There is a Visual Studio .NET Converter Picker. Also a couple of Microsoft Visual Studio .NET ... libraries. No idea if any of them are relevant.

Comment: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.tlb` in Tools menu - References.

Comment: @June7 i turned any i saw with .net on and it still says that its not declared, ill post more of the code when i get home in a bit

Comment: @KL-1 i have that one on already

Comment: Global can only be used in BAS files.

Comment: @KL-1 oh okay so should i make them Public variables instead? I tried that and it still throws the object variable not set. How would you go about making a variable that can be referenced and modified across numerous forms?

Comment: Just put it in a bas file. Just dim it outside of any function. Set the module file as the startup.

Comment: @KL-1, What do you mean by "Global can only be used in BAS files"? I have Global variant variable for an array object declared in Access VBA module and it works just fine. Also have Global Const. Perhaps Public would have been adequate.

Comment: @June7 A BAS file is a module.

Comment: Okay, never seen BAS used in reference to VBA modules. @Collettejorike, since you have them in a general module, they should work. I will do some testing.

Comment: @June7 In the standalone VBA called VB6 forms are save with frm (with an non essential frx file) and modules stored with BAS which is the traditional extension from MS Quick Basic (and QBasic) for MSDos. If you do a save as file it will call it bas for a module. And I've been calling them BAS before modules were thought of. I've been programming in Basic since 1974.

Comment: Okay, I activated the dll and then have no problem declaring, setting, using the Global ArrayList object variable across multiple procedures. However, I would probably just use an Array instead of having to activate the dll.

Comment: @June7 Okay ill do that! Could you give me a quick run down of what you you would do for setting the array to be used and referenced globally?

Comment: @June7 ArrayLists have lots of features like being able to sort. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=net-6.0. Although I would use an ADO RecordSet if I wanted those features.

Comment: If you want to give up on the ArrayList and use Array, do your research and develop code. When you have specific issue with that code, post question. If you want to resolve the ArrayList issue, exactly which line is triggering the error?

Comment: See this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-scope-and-visibility

Comment: I checked all the resources you guys suggested but no luck :( i ended up going a less elegant but functional route using a second list box in my report which would have the list of files in the listbox rowsource of form1 copied over to it and then used that

Answer (score 1):

No need to use an `ArrayList`, the built-in `Collection` object should do just fine. To have global access, wrap it in a property in a Standard module.

```
Private m_collection As Collection

Public Property Get TheCollection() As Collection
    If m_collection Is Nothing Then Set m_collection = New Collection
    Set TheCollection = m_collection 
End Property
```

To call it:

```
TheCollection.Count
```

Don't forget to clear it as the values will be retained.

You could also create a single instance class module, but it's a bit more advanced in terms that you need to export the module, change some of its attributes and import again.

There are a few examples on how to do that here in SO.